# Javascript: Getting the newest array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been thinking about how to display the newest array (because the array list would update from time to time.). I think there's a default function to it but I can't find it. Anyone knows it?

```
var bgImg = new Array();

bgImg[0] = "background.jpg";
bgImg[1] = "background2.jpg";
bgImg[2] = "background3.jpg";
bgImg[3] = "background4.jpg";
```

Comment: Please clarify what you're asking here.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's just that English is my second language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the **last element** of the array,

```
>>> a = ['background1','background2'];
["background1", "background2"]
>>> b = a[a.length-1]
"background2"
```

You shouldn't need to manually assign indexes. Just do bgImg.push('background2.jpg'), and it will mutate the array for you. In your case the syntax would be...

```
var last = bgImg[bgImg.length-1]
```

If you want the **newest** then you need to make a variable and set it with whatever you update when you push the newest one, if it doesn't become the last one.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a little object to handle this for you.

```
function creatImageState() {
    var images = [];
    return {
        get latest() {                    
            return images[images.length - 1];
        },
        set latest (value) {
            images.push(value);
        }
    };
}

var s = creatImageState();

s.latest = "a.png";
s.latest = "b.png";

alert(s.latest);
```

IE doesn't support getters and setters so you probably need to use this.

```
function creatImageState() {
    var images = [];
    return {
        getLatest : function() {                    
            return images[images.length - 1]
        },
        setLatest : function(value) {
            images.push(value);
        }
    };
}

var s = creatImageState();

s.setLatest("a.png");
s.setLatest("b.png");

alert(s.getLatest());
```